# When I switch from Developer Mode to Production my all of my css doesnt load

Tags: magento2, developer-mode, production-mode

When I switch from Developer Mode to Production my all of my css doesnt load.

It looks as if its only loading mobile menus.

Answer (score 1):

In production mode files are not generated at runtime. You should generate it with cli command setup:static-content:deploy.

See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html for more details.